# How can I implement this recursive algorithm to toggle some values on and off depending on their parent's value in a hierarchy

Tags: java

```
protected boolean toggleChildVisibility(long itemId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).getParentItemId() == itemId) {
            Item childItem = items.get(i);

            childItem.setCollapsed(!childItem.isCollapsed());

            toggleChildVisibility(childItem.getItemId());
        }
    }
}
```

I have a list of items, each item either a child or parent item. the root parent items have parentId equal to 0, the children have parentId equal to their parent's id.

Child items can also have child items below them as well.

I need to do something like this. if I click one of them items I need all of its children to collapse if they're expanded or expand if they're collapsed.

The code I have works except for one thing. Say I collapse a child's children items, then I collapse a parent whose children is one of the children I already collapsed. then those children expand, but I don't want them to expand because I have just tried to collapse a higher parent of theirs.

Can anyone help me fix it so that children do not expand when parent is collapsed if they were already collapased

```
public class Item {
    long questionId;
    int depth;

    boolean  collapsed,childrenCollapsed;

    public boolean isChildrenCollapsed() {
        return childrenCollapsed;
    }

    public void setChildrenCollapsed(boolean childrenCollapsed) {
        this.childrenCollapsed = childrenCollapsed;
    }

    public boolean isCollapsed() {
        return collapsed;
    }

    public void setCollapsed(boolean collapsed) {
        this.collapsed = collapsed;
    }
    public long getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel like we are missing some context. Nothing in your question tells directly about how you would be clicking anything, for example. And how can you say a parent collapses if its children are expanding? Isn't that the definition of collapsing to not show the children and if they aren't shown, how could they be expanding?

Comment: I don't think you want to call toggleChildVisibility recursively.  I think all you want to do is collapse a node and everything beneath it when the user clicks collapse, and expand a node and everything underneath it when the user clicks expand.

Comment: @LeeMeador That's my problem. the fact that I toggle their visibility (!childItem.isCollapsed()) means that if I collapse some children at level 5 depth, then I collapse a parent of theirs at level 2, then the children show again because childItem.setCollapsed(!childItem.isCollapsed());

Comment: This would be a lot cleaner if the items were in a tree structure rather than in a flat list.

Comment: Instead of toggle, why not have your method take a boolean state for the value of collapse, and just set that to all of the relevant children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
public void toggleNodeCollapseState(int itemId) {
     for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Item childItem = items.get(i);
        if (childItem.getParentItemId() == itemId) {
            childItem.setCollapsed(!childItem.isCollapsed);
            if (childItem.isCollapsed) {
                hideItemAndDescendants(childItem);
            } else {
                showDescendants(childItem);
            }
        }
     }
}

public void hideItemAndDescendants(Item item) {
    item.hide();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Item childItem = items.get(i);
        if (childItem.getId() == item.getId()) {
              hideItemAndDescendants(childItem);
        }
    }
}

public void showDescendants(Item item) {
    item.hide();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Item childItem = items.get(i);
        if (childItem.getId() == item.getId()) {
            childItem.show();
            if (!childItem.isCollapsed()) {
                showDescendants(childItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key is that there are two issues with nodes

1. Are they collapsed?
2. Are they visible? Or hidden?

You can ignore this distinction but that will result in a collapse always collapsing all the descendants. That means you can't have a node with uncollapsed children showing the grandchildren, collapse the node, uncollapse the node and see those grandchildren in the same collapse state as they were. (I find it particularly irritating to click the wrong node and get everything I carefully expanded below that node collapsed so I have to redo it.)

Clicking a node will then need to toggle the collapsed state.

- A node that is collapsed gets all its descendants hidden but it is still visible.
- A node that's not collapsed gets all its direct children un-hidden.

  - If those direct children are not collapsed apply the rule that an uncollapsed node's children are visible. So their direct children (the grandchildren of the original node) are un-hidden and we go on down un-hiding nodes that are not collapsed.

Comment: How do I find their descendants?

Comment: I am getting a stackoverflow exception pointing to this line `hideItemAndDescendants(childItem)` inside `public void hideItemAndDescendants` I am trying to work it out. if you know the fix please let me know.

Comment: Found the problem `childItem.getId() == item.getId()` should be `childItem.getParentId() == item.getId()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toggling the state at every level independently of the other levels, the code needs to decide whether it's collapsing or expanding the nodes, and then pass that decision down the recursive call tree.